# How to solve this OBIEE configuration error that pops up

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, obiee

I was installing OBIEE, and after going through the various processes. I have installed a database, Jdk, Web logic, BI, with no errors and now to configure OBIEE it shows me this error in the log.

[ERROR] [] [oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager] [tid: 58] [ecid: 0000NGC5QoI3NAWVLyZR8A1VFbi_000004,0] One or More configurations failed. Exiting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imz8P.jpg)

Comment: Open the detailed logs. That screenshot and the error message which is a kind of "header error" don't say much.

Comment: That's the log error message above

Comment: ]]
[2020-08-20T14:36:22.387+01:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.actions] [tid: 58] [ecid: 0000NGC5QoI3NAWVLyZR8A1VFbi_000004,0] Completed zipping up log files to C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\bi\bilogs\bieeconfiglogs_2020-08-20_02-33-05PM.zip on host DESKTOP-7M3NJM9
[2020-08-20T14:36:22.391+01:00] [as] [ERROR] [] [oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager] [tid: 58] [ecid: 0000NGC5QoI3NAWVLyZR8A1VFbi_000004,0] One or More configurations failed. Exiting

Comment: That's not the actual error message. It tells you where the zipped log files are. Open that ZIP and search for the real error.

Comment: This is the error message.

See log file: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\config2020-08-21_11-15-17AM\createExpandedDomain.log
Failed single shot step: Create expanded domain with: Execution of [cmd, /c, C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd, C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\bi\modules\oracle.bi.configassistant\create_base_domain.py, C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi_platform, weblogic, true, 9900, 9901, 9906, DESKTOP-7M3NJM9] failed with exit value 255
Essbase

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be installing that on a desktop operating system. I suggest you read the certifications and supported system configurations before you start installing things.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/obiee-122140-certmatrix-4472983.xlsx

Desktop operating systems were never supported, are not supported and will never be supported.